# Python urllib.request.urlopen on a changing website

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, screen-scraping, urllib

For a small application I want to check our local website, if the public swimming pool is full with guests or not. For that I tried to use urllib and regex in order to readout the html code an search for the status.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import re
import time
link = "https://www.brilon.de/kultur-freizeit-tourismus/hallen-und-freibaeder/waldfreibad-gudenhagen/"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
time.sleep(3)
pageFile = page.read()
plainText= pageFile.decode('UTF-8')
line = re.findall("""<div id="lblAlStatus" style="background-color: green;">Zutritt möglich</div>""", plainText)
print (line)
```

The problem is, that for a  very short amount of time, the website just shows "loading status" instead of "entry possible" or "entry denied" and then after that the actual status. I tried to adress this issue by adding a delay between the urllib.request.urlopen(link) and the actual read(), but that doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The status is returned from a request to an additional endpoint which JavaScript examines the response of and converts to the text you see on the page.

The function doing request is `fnetAlGetStatus()`. The mapping is provided in the file `https://app.briit.de/freibad-ampel/func.js`

```js
function fnetAlUpdateDsp() {
    var lblAlStatus = document.getElementById("lblAlStatus");
    if (fnetAlStatusOk) {
        if (fnetAlStatus === "A") {
            lblAlStatus.innerHTML = "Zutritt m&ouml;glich";
            lblAlStatus.style = "background-color: green;";
        } 
        if (fnetAlStatus === "S") {
            lblAlStatus.innerHTML = "Aktuell Besucherstopp";
            lblAlStatus.style = "background-color: red;";
        } 
        if (fnetAlStatus === "W") {
            lblAlStatus.innerHTML = "Witterungsbedingt geschlossen";
            lblAlStatus.style = "background-color: violet;";
        } 
    }
}
```

You can recreate the request and provide your own mapping to generate the output text:

```
import requests, json

status = {'A':'Zutritt möglich',
          'S':'Aktuell Besucherstopp',
          'W':'Witterungsbedingt geschlossen'}

r = requests.get('https://app.briit.de/freibad-ampel/api.php?op=getStatus')
print(status[json.loads(r.text)['AlStatus']])
```

Looking at the js it seems like there is error handling as well where '' will be for errors i.e.

```
status = {'A':'Zutritt möglich',
          'S':'Aktuell Besucherstopp',
          'W':'Witterungsbedingt geschlossen',
          '': 'Error'}
```

Comment: you are a lifesaver